# Ionic2:Two different menus on two root file

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have created two root files in an ionic 2 project. One is app.component and the other is report-menu. I imported report-menu module in the app.component.module.ts file. One of my menus is in app.html and the other one is in report-menu.html. But its not working. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible to achieve this. But both the menus need to be defined in `app.component.html`.

Once you load the `report-menu` module, you need to use the `MenuController` api to disable the default menu and enable the menu related to `report-menu`.

So the naswer is, you can multiple menus defined in app.component.html and enable them on page basis.

Comment: but I don't want to load all those pages in app.component.ts.I want reports section to be completely excluded.As when a user clicks on reports then only all the files will be loaded.Like this, I have to load all the files in app.component.ts.

Comment: No, you dont have to load all the files. You can load report-menu lazily as usual. You just need to have the sidemenu defined in app.component.html. And on loading the report page, you can emit a event which will give links etc to app.component.ts to render your menu specific to report page